# About Generalized Hypergeometric Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, hypergeometric-function

I have a definition of Generalized hypergeometric function as $$_1F_2(a_1;b_1,b_2;z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a_1)_n}{(b_1)_n (b_2)_n} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$ 
My question is, what will be the result if $a_1$ equals to zero? I couldn't come across any definition defining this special case.

Thanks.

Comment: Because it is not a *special* case: if $a_1=0$ then $(a_1)_n=0$ for any $n\geq 1$ and $(a_1)_0=1$, so the whole series boils down to its first term.

Comment: $(0)_0 = 1, (0)_n=0,\quad n>0. $
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html

Answer (score 1):

This has already been pointed out in the answers but I will put it here for the sake of completeness.

This question really comes down the the behavoir of the Pochhammer symbol. Begin with
$$
_1F_2(a_1;b_1,b_2;z) = 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(a_1)_n}{(b_1)_n (b_2)_n} \frac{z^n}{n!}.
$$
By definition, $(a_1)_n=\frac{\Gamma(a_1+n)}{\Gamma(a_1)}$ and as $a_1\to 0$ we find $1/\Gamma(a_1)\sim a_1+\mathcal O(a_1^2)$. Therefore, in the limit $\Gamma(a_1+n)/\Gamma(a_1)\to 0$. Hence, the series terms for $n\geq 1$ vanish and
$$
_1F_2(0;b_1,b_2;z) = 1.
$$

Comment: Unless ... b_1 or b_2 is zero as well :)

Comment: @rrogers Point we'll taken. Glad to hear from you sir!